# Why is the -f flag not working in ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg.output(audioo, videoo, name).global_args("-f mp4").run()
```

I have this code which takes in the audio and video, and gives the output file a name.
Then I have .global_args, which takes in the arguments, but, when I try to run the script
it says

```
Unrecognized option 'f mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

But, if I use a flag like, -y which looks like this

```
ffmpeg.output(audioo, videoo, names).global_args("-y").run()
```

it works but then in the name string, It needs to be like 'output.mp4'
but I want to use the -f flag so It could be 'output' only, and the format is decided by the flag.

You may think it's useless but if it's needed I could explain my reasons further.

Comment: For those of us who haven't seen this Python library... does it support `global_args("-f", "mp4")`? I'd certainly _expect_ it to. That, or something else, like `global_args(["-f", "mp4"])`; check the library's docs.

Comment: Spaces are _literal data_; it's only shells that split on them into separate arguments. A Python library that unnecessarily calls a shell (and expects values that it's passed to include shell quoting) is a Python library I would never recommend anyone use.